# Using Remix OS(Android-x86) terminal shell to turn off the touchscreen

Tags: adb, touchscreen, terminal, echo

I have recently installed Remix OS on my PC, and now it's like a craze. Nothing worked. I always think it was the problem with the touchscreen, because EVERY operating system I used on my PC, the mouse jumped everywhere. But on Remix OS, it isn't like that. The mouse didn't jumped. But I have a more serious problem. It won't accept any input that uses mouse, and I have to use the keyboard all the time. I found on the system the terminal, which I think can be used to turn off the touchscreen. Is there any way I can turn off the touchscreen using adb or echo?

Comment: Yes, it is in beta. And I asked that how to disable my crazy touchscreen, not to sleep the system. Second, what does `adb shell input keyevent 26` do?

Comment: Valid point. Sorry for the incorrect solution.

Comment: Is there any way to turn off touch screen ?